# Flash error: ReferenceError: Error #1065:

Tags: flash, banner

I created a banner, and when opnening on my browser, I get this error,

Error #1033: Cpool entry 18 is wrong type.
and tha after that I get

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MainTimeline is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Cpool error is due to you compiling with a newer SDK and trying to run with an old player.

Comment: thanks, u are right, I was using old player, it worked fine with new version